# Magento2 Get Shipping Address Before Placing Order

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to check the shipping address of an order being placed using an event observer.  I need to get the shipping address before the order is placed so I can cross reference it to places I do not wish to ship to, and either proceed with the order or throw an exception.

app/code/ob7/RestrictedRegions/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
  <event name="sales_order_place_before">
    <observer name="ob7_RestrictedRegions_sales_order_place_before" instance="ob7\RestrictedRegions\Observer\OrderPlaceBefore"/>
  </event>
</config>
```

app/code/ob7/RestrictedRegions/Observer/OrderPlaceBefore.php:

```
<?php namespace ob7\RestrictedRegions\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\PaymentException;

class OrderPlaceBefore implements ObserverInterface
{

   public function execute(Observer $observer)
   {   

       $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
       $shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();
       throw new PaymentException(__('Error will appear here'));            
   }
}
```

This results in an error.  Can someone advise me on the proper way to collect the shipping address here?

Removing $shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress(); stops the error.  But then how do I get the shipping address?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the quote object to get the shipping address for before placing order event(observer) data.

> $order = $observer->getEvent()->getData('order');
>
> $quote= $order->getQuote();
>
> $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();